# how to check difference betwen master and slave in slony replication?

Tags: database, postgresql, pg

I want to know how much the master lag behind the slave in teems of rows ?
How can i see this ? I mean in which column ? 
I have tried to check sl_status table but i think it is not helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sl_status` is the way to go.  You can get the lag in terms of events and time.  There is no such thing as lag in rows in Slony.